# Combinatorics assignment problem with set requirements

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Currently working on a problem, which I believe can be solved with some form of assignment algorithm. I have a set of resources and requirements, where each requirement has some combinatoric requirement of resources to be met. The objective is to try and optimize how many tasks are met, with unmet tasks being as close as possible.

For example, a task may be satisfied if it has resource A, or resource B and resource C. Another may require resource A and D. Thus, given resources A-D, the ideal assignment is B,C to task one and A,D to task two.

I think the best path to approach this is through some sort of bipartite assignment, or to potentially expand this to a multi level graph to better modal the combinatoric relationship and utilize some form of max-flow approach.

Any insight or direction to similar problems or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if this helps but it looks like a more general version of the set-packing problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_packing

Comment: Integer programming is the easiest tool for this problem. Look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming

Comment: Definitely helped. I think I can reduce this to an instance of the set-packing problem and solve it that way. Can anyone confirm if this reduction will work? For AND conditions, simply construct a set with both options. For example, A and B is a set (A,B). For an OR condition, split into two sets, each which share a new sentinel value. For example, A or B should be (A,X) and (B,X). Then, having a single X resource with set-packing will guarantee only A or B is selected.